# Spring Data REST - Why hibernate fetches children entity with FetchType.LAZY?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a simple use case where I created 2 entities `Account` & `AccountDetail`.

These entities have a one-to-one relationship as shown below:
[table relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YNYb.png)

The `Account` entity:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private AccountDetail accountDetail;

}
```

The `AccountDetail` entity:

```
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class AccountDetail {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @MapsId
    private Account account;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;
}
```

I am using Spring Boot (v2.3.0) with following dependencies:
- Spring Data JPA: to persist entities using Hibernate
- Rest Repositories: to expose repositories over REST endpoints

The issue is that Hibernate is fetching the `AccountDetail` entity even though I specified `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`.

You can see the 2 sql statements in the log:
[hibernate log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTat1.png)

---

### **What I already tried:**

**Using Projection:**

```
@Projection(types = {Account.class})
public interface AccountProjection {
    String getUsername();
}
```

With the following GET request http://localhost:8080/accounts/1?projection=accountProjection, I get:

```
   {
      "username": "warrior24",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/accounts/1"
        },
        "account": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/accounts/1{?projection}",
          "templated": true
        },
        "accountDetail": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/accounts/1/accountDetail"
        }
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, with this solution, it still makes 2 sql requests.

**Using Hibernate Bytecode Enhancement with `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)`**

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
private AccountDetail accountDetail;
```

Even this solution does not solve the issue.

### Conclusion

I am not sure to understand why hibernate is fetching the child. At the moment it is not a big issue, but if the number of database records gets big it could impact on the performance.

Does anybody have a similar issue and maybe know how to solve it?

---

**Update: Including the debug log for a GET request**

`2020-05-27 15:23:58.414  INFO 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-3].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-27 15:23:58.414  INFO 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-27 15:23:58.414 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2020-05-27 15:23:58.415 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2020-05-27 15:23:58.415  INFO 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2020-05-27 15:23:58.415 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/accounts/1", parameters={}
2020-05-27 15:23:58.416 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped to org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController#getItemResource(RootResourceInformation, Serializable, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler, HttpHeaders)
2020-05-27 15:23:58.416 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-05-27 15:23:58.417 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] stomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method 'findById' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
2020-05-27 15:23:58.417 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1137877934<open>)] for JPA transaction
2020-05-27 15:23:58.417 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
2020-05-27 15:23:58.417 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Setting JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@646683728 wrapping conn193: url=jdbc:h2:mem:f0df200a-97ea-4e5b-9f80-050ff9a550f7 user=SA] read-only
2020-05-27 15:23:58.417 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@3a65c273]
2020-05-27 15:23:58.417 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.password as password2_0_0_, account0_.username as username3_0_0_ from account account0_ where account0_.id=?
2020-05-27 15:23:58.417 TRACE 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2020-05-27 15:23:58.418 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select accountdet0_.account_id as account_3_1_0_, accountdet0_.first_name as first_na1_1_0_, accountdet0_.last_name as last_nam2_1_0_ from account_detail accountdet0_ where accountdet0_.account_id=?
2020-05-27 15:23:58.418 TRACE 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2020-05-27 15:23:58.418 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2020-05-27 15:23:58.418 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1137877934<open>)]
2020-05-27 15:23:58.418 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@646683728 wrapping conn193: url=jdbc:h2:mem:f0df200a-97ea-4e5b-9f80-050ff9a550f7 user=SA]
2020-05-27 15:23:58.418 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2020-05-27 15:23:58.421 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/hal+json', given [*/*] and supported [application/hal+json]
2020-05-27 15:23:58.421 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [Resource { content: Account(id=1, username=warrior24, password=1234), links: [<http://localhost:8080 (truncated)...]
2020-05-27 15:23:58.421 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.d.r.w.j.PersistentEntityJackson2Module : Serializing PersistentEntity org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl@45b7be72.
2020-05-27 15:23:58.423 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource : No properties file found for [classpath:rest-messages] - neither plain properties nor XML
2020-05-27 15:23:58.424 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource : No properties file found for [classpath:rest-messages_en] - neither plain properties nor XML
2020-05-27 15:23:58.424 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource : No properties file found for [classpath:rest-messages_en_GB] - neither plain properties nor XML
2020-05-27 15:23:58.426 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-05-27 15:23:58.426 DEBUG 2119 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK`

Comment: Could it be from the equalsAndHashcode calculation?

Comment: According to your current configuration when you fetch the `Account` entity, Hibernate should not be making an additional call to get the `AccountDetail` entity. `AccountDetail` get initialized only when an explicit call to getter method for `AccountDetail` in `Account` happens. So can you debug and check if the second query is made along with first or somewhere else in your logic

Comment: Hi @Vishnu, yes I agree with you. This is why I am confused. I edited my post to add the debug log.

Comment: I think the `toString` method created by `@Builder` annotated might be making a call to the `getter` of `AccountDetail`

Comment: Most likely hibernate needs to know if it is a null value or if it should create a proxy and thus loading the relation upfront. You can only avoid it by marking the relation as mandatory. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33032122/869225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION (kind of)

Okay I think I found the solution but unfortunately it is not compatible with Spring Data Rest.

By adding `optional = false`, you can tell hibernate that you will ensure that the child reference will never be null (in my case `AccountDetail`).

Therefore, it will not need to fetch the child in order to check if it has to create a proxy or assign `NULL`.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
private AccountDetail accountDetail;
```

The issue with this solution is that you cannot create a new `Account` resource using the POST endpoint provided with the `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation.
Since, it now expects the `AccountDetail` to be not null, you need to provide the link of this resource in the JSON (which is not existing yet). And you cannot create the `AccountDetail` resource because it uses as primary key the foreign key from the Account table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@JsonIgnore` annotation that indicates that the annotated method or field is to be ignored by introspection-based serialization and deserialization functionality.

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private AccountDetail accountDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` annotation to exclude `accountDetail` from `equals` and `hashCode` methods

```
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude    
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
                private AccountDetail accountDetail;
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried it but I get the same. I am wondering if Hibernate really fetch the data or it is just that the LOG is showing the query for each entity (parent + children)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50919847/12199915 looks like the same problem

Comment: Not really, in my case, I do not use a default excerptProjection:  

`@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

}`

Comment: Try to exclude acountDetails field with annotation @RestResource(exported = false)

Comment: Okay, I tried that but it only remove the link of this `AccountDetail` resource in the JSON response. I still see in the LOG that it is getting fetched.